# How to turn a wordlist into a word array

Tags: php, html, arrays

I am making a hangman game and I want the words to be chosen from an array of words if someone could tell me a quick way to do this whilst not breaking my code that would be great. I would like to get rid of the (words.list) and replace it with an array

```
<?php
$letters = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z');

if (empty($_POST)) {
    $words = explode("\n", file_get_contents('words.list'));
    $right = array_fill_keys($letters, '.');
    $wrong = array();
    shuffle($words);
    $word = strtolower($words[0]);
    $rightstr = serialize($right);
    $wrongstr = serialize($wrong);
    $wordletters = str_split($word);
    $show = '';
    foreach ($wordletters as $letter) {
        $show .= $right[$letter];
    }
} else {
    $word = $_POST['word'];
    $guess = strtolower($_POST['guess']);
    $right = unserialize($_POST['rightstr']);
    $wrong = unserialize($_POST['wrongstr']);
    $wordletters = str_split($word);
    if (stristr($word, $guess)) {
        $show = '';
        $right[$guess] = $guess;
        $wordletters = str_split($word);
        foreach ($wordletters as $letter) {
            $show .= $right[$letter];
        }

    } else {
        $show = '';
        $wrong[$guess] = $guess;
        if (count($wrong) == 6) {
            $show = $word;
        } else {
            foreach ($wordletters as $letter) {
                $show .= $right[$letter];
            }
        }
    }
    $rightstr = serialize($right);
    $wrongstr = serialize($wrong);
}

?>
Bad Guesses : <?php echo implode(', ', $wrong) ?><br />
<?php echo $show ?><br />
<form method='post'>
<input name='guess' />
<input type='hidden' name='word' value='<?php echo $word ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='rightstr' value='<?php echo $rightstr ?>' />
<input type='hidden' name='wrongstr' value='<?php echo $wrongstr ?>' />
<input type='submit' value='guess' />
</form>
<a href="hangman.php">Start Over</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with php's `var_export`

first create the itial array

```
$words = explode("\n", file_get_contents('words.list'));
```

storing:

```
file_put_contents( 'array.php', '<?php return '.var_export( $words, true ).";\n" );
```

the you can just use

`$words=include('array.php');` for future access